# How to pass command line argument to kubectl create command

Tags: kubernetes, command-line, command-line-arguments, kubectl

If I run the `kubectl create -f deployment.yaml` command with
the following `deployment.yaml` file, everything succeeds.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
 name: my_app
 labels:
  app: my_app
spec:
 containers:
  - name: my_app
    image: docker:5000/path_to_my_custom_image
    args: ["my_special_argument"]
```

However, now I want to have a custom "my_special_argument"
as follows

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
 name: my_app
 labels:
  app: my_app
spec:
 containers:
  - name: my_app
    image: docker:5000/path_to_my_custom_image
    args: ["$(ARG)"]
```

and I want to somehow set the value of $ARG$ when I execute the `kubectl create -f deployment.yaml` command. How to do that?

I am looking for something like:
`kubectl create -f deployment.yaml --ARG=new_arg`

Can such command be executed?

Comment: You can't do this with kubectl. See kustomize or helm for creating a template from a Deployment.

Answer (score 7):

You can use Environment variables in the `deployment.yaml`

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
 name: my_app
 labels:
  app: my_app
spec:
 containers:
  - name: my_app
    image: docker:5000/path_to_my_custom_image
    env:
    - name: SPECIAL_ARG_VAL
      value: "my_special_argument_val_for_my_app"
    args: ["$(SPECIAL_ARG_VAL)"]
```

Also, you can load the value for environment variables using Secrets or Configmaps.

[Here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/#configure-all-key-value-pairs-in-a-configmap-as-container-environment-variables) is an example loading value from configmap

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
 name: my_app
 labels:
  app: my_app
spec:
 containers:
  - name: my_app
    image: docker:5000/path_to_my_custom_image
    env:
    - name: SPECIAL_ARG_VAL
      valueFrom:
        configMapKeyRef:
          name: special-config
          key: SPECIAL_VAL_KEY
    args: ["$(SPECIAL_ARG_VAL)"]
```

You can create the configmap using `kubectl` as the following, but recommend to have a separate yaml file.

```
kubectl create configmap special-config --from-literal=SPECIAL_VAL_KEY=my_special_argument_val_for_my_app
```

You can even remove the `args` from the pod yaml above if you had the same environment variable defined in the Dockerfile for the image.

Comment: but how do you set a value of that SPECIAL_ARG_VAL using `kubectl create -f ...` command?

Comment: Ah, you can set the value for env variable from configmap or secrets.
Here is an example loading value from configmap:
https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/#use-configmap-defined-environment-variables-in-pod-commands

Comment: @mercury0114 I have updated the answer for using configmap.