# Can we pass the argument for Kubectl create command via terminal

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I have deployment yaml file where I am setting up one ARG.

```
args['--country=usa']
```

It runs perfectly and pod will be up with this argument. But for different country name, I need to change this yaml for argument and then run

kubectl create -f deploy.yml command again and again

Is there any way to pass this arg through create command

I tried kubectl create -f deploy.yml '--country=usa' but it seems like this is not the correct way to pass it

Comment: I believe [kustomize](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/manage-kubernetes-objects/kustomization/) was designed to solve that problem, as will `kubectl patch` with enough shell quoting :-)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is no simple way to do that.
Here are some related questions.

Using env variable and configmap:
[How to pass command line argument to kubectl create command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60449786/how-to-pass-command-line-argument-to-kubectl-create-command)

Using Helm:
[Kubernetes Deployment - Pass arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61946064/kubernetes-deployment-pass-arguments)

Comment: ok. I am using Helm now to pass the argument I am still not able to change the value. Can you suggest any example in Helm to pass dynamic parameters